# Android: Send mail with standard mail app on button click

Tags: android, email, send

i'd like to send the content of a TextEdit element to an email address. Ive coded this few lines of code already and theyre working so far:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email@mailaddress.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Mail Subject");
            mailcontent = mailcontentBox.getText().toString();
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mailcontent);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Insert title for dialog box."));
        }
```

This code opens up the "Send to.." view, where i can choose between the different apps. But is it possible to just view mailing apps or even better, directly switch to the standard mailing app?

At the moment, theres anything in the "Send to.." view like mailing apps, whatsapp, facebook, twitter etc.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn’t use `Intent.createChooser()` to launch an email Intent. Users most likely have a preferred email app that they want to be able to select as default app.

Just do `startActivity(emailIntent);`

Comment: That helped a lot. Now i can choose my mail app and click "use this every time". Thank you. But now i have the problem, that i clicked "use this every time" and i need to undo this to check some other things. I tried to reinstall it, but that doesnt help. Any suggestions?

Comment: @lordzwieback yes you have to reset the app settings
`Settings--->Apps-->Reset App Preferences`

Comment: also check articles like this one http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remove-change-set-default-apps-android/

Comment: damn, that only works if i do it for all apps. well, okay then. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: @lordzwieback in the application info of your email app there is the Open by default option. There you can find the clear defaults button. This will clear all the default open with for this particular app

Comment: thanks to your article i found a better way. go to settings - apps - the default app you want to "de-default" - there you can reset the default links to other apps

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` instead of `Intent.ACTION_SEND`.
As it said [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email).

Comment: This gets me a view with text "This action cant be executed from any app."